# MvxSpinner/MvxListView doesn't work with MvvmCross Light (Chimp) from axml

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

In Android project I'm trying to add databindings using CrossLight part of MvvmCross.
Bindings to standard TextView/Buttons work great. But simplest markup with Mvx.Control:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <Mvx.MvxListView />
</LinearLayout>
```

Gives an error

`"Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class Mvx.MvxListView"`

The same thing is with `Mvx.Spinner`.
However, when instantiating it from code in `Activity.OnCreate`:

```
_bindingContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext(this, new LayoutInflaterProvider(LayoutInflater), _viewModel);
var view = (LinearLayout)_bindingContext.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.Main, null);
SetContentView(view);
var spinner = new MvxSpinner(this, null, new MvxAdapter(this, _bindingContext));
view.AddView(spinner);
```

Everything works great (including bindings). What am I doing wrong? Is this scenario supported in general?
Or maybe I should reference anything else except nuget `MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore`?

P.S. Haven't found any samples with custom controls and CrossLight neither on [github](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/CrossLight), nor on [N+1 videos](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/n30-crosslight-aka-project-chimp-n1.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use namespace abbreviations within your non-MvvmCross application, then you'll need to add those abbreviations. This can be done using a custom binding builder or using a 'light' setup step like:

```
    var viewResolver = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAxmlNameViewTypeResolver>();
    viewResolver.ViewNamespaceAbbreviations["Mvx"] = "Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views";
    viewResolver.ViewNamespaceAbbreviations["MyApp"] = "MyApp.Controls";
```

---

When doing this within a full MvvmCross application, then you can override the `Setup` property `ViewNamespaceAbbreviations`

```
    protected override IDictionary<string, string> ViewNamespaceAbbreviations
    {
        get
        {
            var toReturn = base.ViewNamespaceAbbreviations;
            toReturn["MyApp"] = "MyApp.UI.Droid.Controls";
            return toReturn;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've tried to make abbreviations work using a 'light' setup based on your github crosslight example, but I don't know where to call the viewResolver.

Comment: Got working using the Mvx.CallbackWhenRegistered on my 'light' setup.

Answer (score 1):

When markup was changed to using the full namespace and `layout_width` and `layout_height` attribute was added it started to work!

```
  <Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxSpinner
    android:id="@+id/MySpinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    />
```

It was found when I switched to default Android inflater and it was complaining about missing `layout_width` in Exceptions.